# prolog predicates cf boolean valued functions

Tags: prolog

Guides teaching prolog are careful to dissuade students from thinking that **predicates** are **functions**.

After some thought, the idea that predicates are **boolean functions** seems valid.

Predicates have zero of finite input parameters, and their output is either true or false, success or fail.

**Question:**  Is this dangerous to think of prolog predicates as boolean valued functions? What are the limitations of this analogy?

---

The following is the closest I have found to discussing this question meaningfully:

https://www.reddit.com/r/prolog/comments/f48grt/difference_between_predicate_and_function/

Comment: I think they are closer to *generator* functions, since they are often used to produce multiple solutions via backtracking. Procedural examples: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Comment: Sure `test(X) :- X>2.` seems like a boolean C# function. but `test(X) :- X = 5; false.` which has "output" of X=5 and true at the same time? Weird for Python. On backtracking (weird for JavaScript) it has no output for X (where did one output go, that's weird for C) only false (the output changed? Weird for Java). Throw in `writeln()` to argue about whether stdout ("standard output") counts as output or doesn't. And what better feeling do you get for Prolog from being taught this? Better to spend the time *trying things in the toplevel* to feel how predicates behave.

Answer (score 1):

You can call predicates boolean functions, but look at this:

```
?- member(a, [a,b,c]).
true ;
false.
```

Also this:

```
?- member(X, [a,b,c]).
X = a ;
X = b ;
X = c.
```

Functions don't do that as far as I know. "Predicates" as used in procedural languages like [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/predicate) and [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.10/howto/functional.html?highlight=predicate#selecting-elements) are either true of false, once. They are not both true and false, nor are they true three times in a row.

EDIT: I can't tell which one is worse, reddit or stackoverflow. Both are terrible places to learn anything you didn't know already.